# Unity3D MultiplyPoint matrix confusion

Tags: c#, matrix, unity-game-engine, transform

This [multiply point function](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint.html)
simply multiplies up to a 4*4 matrix by a vector 3 or 4.

I am trying to replicate this function using only maths as I'm using shaders.

The maths itself is nothing spectacular, just the dot product of each column by each row to get the resulting transform.

My problem is that unity is returning my transform matrix as a 2*4,

[image: transform matrix values]

and my vector to transform is a Vector4 (Vector 3 world position with an added 1 in the fourth component)

My conclusion being that this Unity function must do some other method before than standard matrix multiplication,any thoughts on this is welcomed.

[image: Edit: Code extract]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This multiply point function simply multiplies up to a 4*4 matrix by a Vector3 or Vector4.

That's actually wrong, it only multiplies by a Vector3 - check the doco

Issue: to be helpful, Unity annoyingly "casts" between Vector2, Vector3, Vector4 (in different ways, that sometimes do and sometimes don't make sense).

If you're giving it a Vector4 as the argument, **you are not actually getting what you think - its' "casting" it to a Vector3** in an attempt to be helpful.

I hope, that's the problem here!

Just for the sake of any new chums googling here, in `a=b.MultiplyPoint(c)` we have b (that's b, not a or c) is a FOUR (i.e. a "movement") and c is a THREE (position) and the result a is a THREE (position).

Comment: Thanks, interesting as the reason I formatting to V4 was to match the 4*4 transform matrix. I've unfortunately tested with both V3 and V4 and got the same results.

Comment: Really sorry that was not it.  I'm a little confused since in `MultiplyPoint` we have `a=b.MultiplyPoint(c)` where b (that's b, not a or c) is a FOUR (ie a "movement") and c is a THREE (position) and the result a is a THREE (position).  In your case, regarding c (that's c, not a or b), you're "making it a FOUR" (I believe by "adding seven ones" around the two edges).  I'm afraid, I really don't understand that - I'm not sure what you're "aiming to do" - you know?  Sorry couldn't help more.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'm confused as to if by default it casts to v4 with W == 1, or if I input a V4, it with W==1, it casts to V3.
And I'm simply trying to replicate this function, perhaps this image will help:

Comment: Hi Jamie.  It DEFINITELY casts your "c" argument, which you're supplying as a FOUR, to a THREE.

Comment: Okey thanks, thanks progress. I'm adding an edit soon with a screenshot of my code

Comment: TBC though, I just don't understand (I'm afraid) why you're trying to "do that operation" to a FOUR.  For me it has no physical reality, and it also has no mathematical reality you know!  :O

Comment: Is it possible you're looking for more `Vector4.Scale` ??

Comment: Regarding Vector 4 cast: I was just trying it out to test how unity casts, to my surprise I didn't get any difference, now I know it's casting to V3 - Thanks :).
And ,to my knowledge the rows in one matrix must match the columns in the other, which was part of my reasoning.
Hope That helps.

Comment: And no not scale , but thanks for trying. I'll let you know of my results if I get hold of a solution.

Comment: Say, since I more or less answered the specific problem in THIS question, perhaps you could "Tick" it mate .. it means YOU get points and your questions less moderated as a new user.  Keeps the site tidy - I'm very anal.  I'm trying to find the answer to your new question....

Comment: Yeaaaah I call it close enough, and good effort regardless :)

Comment: And I've looked at the function, and it does process vector 4 , just outputs xyz only, but anyway, a I said, good effort.